# I click "run" it keeps on loading with no signs of running or stopping

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessingGame {

  public static void main (String [] args) {

    Random rand = new Random ();
    int numberToGuess = rand.nextInt (100);
    int numberOfTries = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    int guess;

    boolean win = false;

    while (win == false); {

      System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 100:");
      guess = input.nextInt (); 
      numberOfTries++;

      if (guess == numberToGuess) {
        win = true;
      }

      else if (guess > numberToGuess) {
        System.out.println ("You guessed too low mate!");
      }

      else if (guess > numberToGuess) {
        System.out.println ("You guessed too high mate!") ;

        System.out.println("You win!!");
        System.out.println("The random number WAS!" + numberToGuess);
        System.out.println("It took you a wopping" + numberOfTries + "TRIES!");

      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is my code and when I try to run it, it basically gets stuck here:

Welcome to Dr Java.
Working directory is U:\Downloads
run GuessingGame

How do I fix this problem to where as I can run the program properly with no errors as above?

Answer (score 2):

I see two bugs.

```
while (win == false); {
```

should be

```
while (win == false) {
```

(or `while(!win) {`) because the semicolon creates an empty loop body. And

```
  else if (guess > numberToGuess) {
    System.out.println ("You guessed too low mate!");
  }
```

should be

```
  else if (guess < numberToGuess) {
    System.out.println ("You guessed too low mate!");
  }
```

Or you have two tests on higher (and this way makes sense).

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on Elliott's answer:

```
while (win == false); {
    // etc. etc. etc.
}
```

is equivalent to

```
while (win == false)
     ;  // empty statement, does nothing
{
    // The body, which really isn't part of the while loop any more
}
```

which has the same effect as

```
while (win == false) { 
}

{
    // The part that isn't really part of the loop
}
```

Since `win` starts out at `false`, this will keep looping and doing nothing until `win` somehow gets changed to `true`, which of course will never happen.  That's why the program is getting stuck--it's in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

modify your `while` block as `do-while` block as following

```
do{
      System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 100:");
      guess = input.nextInt (); 
      numberOfTries++;

      if (guess == numberToGuess) {
        win = true;
      }

      else if (guess < numberToGuess) {
        System.out.println ("You guessed too low mate!");
      }

      else if (guess > numberToGuess) {
        System.out.println ("You guessed too high mate!") ;

        System.out.println("You win!!");
        System.out.println("The random number WAS!" + numberToGuess);
        System.out.println("It took you a wopping" + numberOfTries + "TRIES!");

      }
    }while(win==false);
```

Comment: You missed the second bug. This still has two tests on `guess > numberToGuess`.